# selenium form submit erases required camps although button is visible and clickable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with chromedriver. I fill a form where there is a required field. Then I click the submit_and_stay button. Normally the click should send the info to the server and create an entry. This has a java-script. The click works but the required field disappears and the submit restarts. Other fields remain visible.
I have explicit wait,
I have scrolled to the button, I have hovered over it and I use EC.until it is clickable.
But still it fails to work. I used normal click, submit, key send return, then I used actions click and still it fails.
Here is the code:

```
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(10)
id_box=driver.find_element_by_name("submitAddproductAndStay")

id_box=WebDriverWait(driver, 
50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#product-seo > 
div:nth-child(8) > button:nth-child(3)')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(id_box).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", id_box);
time.sleep(5)
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click(on_element = id_box).perform()
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you provide the website ur testing or the html?

Comment: the web page has a login first but the button element is conatined in a footer:  <div class="panel-footer">
  <a href="index.php?controller=AdminProducts&amp;token=cd4a6de56eb665ed850ff1d5fbe7df88" class="btn btn-default"><i class="process-icon-cancel"></i> Annuler</a>
  <button type="submit" name="submitAddproduct" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="process-icon-save"></i> Enregistrer</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submitAddproductAndStay" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="process-icon-save"></i> Enregistrer et rester</button>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

After loosing 2 days on this, I figured out that the only way to go around this is to execute the click event by direct execute.javascript in the code:
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

As strange as it can be!!